# How to draw sprites using a function in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Here is my code:

```
Create (){
spawn();
}
function spawn(){
var sprite = this.physics.add.sprite(50,50,'spritesheet','red.png');
}
```

Now when I run this code I get an error like:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined*

The problem is with the sprite part of the function but when I use the same code in the create function directly it works. So how do I make it work inside an external function.

Comment: It's about wrong `this` context. Can you try calling `spawn.bind(this)` and then `spawn()`?

Comment: It worked. Consider moving it to a answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments:
In `Create()`, `this` is something different than `this` in `spawn()`.

Therefore it needs to be bound properly between those functions.
One way to do this:

```js
Create() {
    spawn.bind(this)
    spawn();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
class myScene extends Phaser.Scene {

    constructor (config)
    {
      super(config);
    }

    preload ()
    {
      this.load.image('dude', 'sprites/phaser-dude.png')
    }
   
    create () 
    {
      this.spawn()
    }
    
    spawn()
    {
      var sprite = this.physics.add.sprite(50, 50, 'dude')
    }
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    loader: {
      baseURL: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/samme/phaser-examples-assets@v2.0.0/assets/',
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    },
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    physics: {
      default: 'arcade',
      arcade: {
        gravity: { y: 1 }
      }
  },
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

game.scene.add('myScene', myScene, true);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.17.0/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```